# How do you parse brackets from path string on a variable return in Hugo?

Tags: go, yaml, hugo

I am writing a layout template for a Hugo generated post/page.  The .yaml header is

```
image:
  - post/mytitle/image.jpg
```

The template incorporates the variable in Hugo as

```
{{ .Params.Image }}
```

When served, the variable is returned as

```
[post/mytitle/image.jpg]
```

My html then becomes

```
<img src="[post/mytitle/image.jpg]"/>
```

which is 404 in the browser.  I've tried a number of Hugo functions to no avail like `{{ trim .Param.Image "[]" }}` and `{{ subset .Params.Image 1 -1 }}` and `{{ print .Params.Image }}`. Each time Hugo returned the error: "error calling substr: unable to cast []string{"post/mytitle/image.jpg"} of type []string to string".

How do I get the variable to return the string without the brackets, or alternatively, how do I omit the brackets from the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Go template, you access an item in a slice with `index`:

```
{{ index .Params.Image 0 }}
```

The question is why the value is a sequence in the first place. You could simply do

```yaml
image:
  post/mytitle/image.jpg
```

Then you could keep the original syntax since it is now a simple value, not a sequence.

If you want to possibly include multiple images, you'd do

```
{{ range .Params.Image }}<img src="{{.}}">{{ end }}
```

Then you can have

```yaml
image:
  - post/mytitle/image.jpg
  - post/mytitle/anotherimage.jpg
```